# limit users in group chat of whatsapp by an android app

Tags: java, android, chat, whatsapp

i m trying to developing an app where i want to monitor whatsapp group chat and limit users e.g max 5 users can join if 6th coming, ignore or remove most inactive and add new user to chat
i have no idea how can i do that ? it requires root acess or not?
is there any api available to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Yowsup](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup) which is a Python library. You will need to setup a separate WhatsApp account that logs into the WhatsApp servers using this library. This account will need to be the "owner" of the groups and will need to manage adding and removing users from the chat. The code will also need to monitor the chat traffic to figure out who is talking. The code you develop does not need to run all the time.

You will need to register listeners for a number of WhatsApp events. Some of your init code will look like this:

```
class WhatsappClient:
 def __init__(self):
    atexit.register(self.exitfunction)

    connectionManager = YowsupConnectionManager()
    connectionManager.setAutoPong(True)
    self.signalsInterface = connectionManager.getSignalsInterface()
    self.methodsInterface = connectionManager.getMethodsInterface()

    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("auth_success", self.onAuthSuccess)
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("auth_fail", self.onAuthFailed)
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("message_received", self.onMessageReceived)
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("receipt_messageSent", self.onMessageSent)
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("disconnected", self.onDisconnected)
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("group_messageReceived", self.onGroup_messageReceived)   
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("notification_groupParticipantAdded", self.onNotification_groupParticipantAdded)
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("notification_groupParticipantRemoved", self.onNotification_groupParticipantRemoved)
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("group_gotInfo", self.onGroup_gotInfo)
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("group_gotParticipants", self.onGroup_gotParticipants)
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("group_subjectReceived", self.onGroup_subjectReceived)
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("notification_groupPictureUpdated", self.onNotification_groupPictureUpdated)
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("group_setSubjectSuccess", self.onGroup_setSubjectSuccess)
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("group_createSuccess", self.onGroup_createSuccess)
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("group_createFail", self.onGroup_createFail)
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("group_endSuccess", self.onGroup_endSuccess)
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("group_addParticipantsSuccess", self.onGroup_addParticipantsSuccess)
    self.signalsInterface.registerListener("group_removeParticipantsSuccess", self.onGroup_removeParticipantsSuccess)
```

## some examples of method implementations above:

```
def onGroup_messageReceived(self, messageId, gjid, author, content, timestamp, receiptRequested, pushName):
    formattedDate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    log("Group message %s - %s (%s):%s"%(gjid, pushName, author, content))
    if receiptRequested:
        self.methodsInterface.call("message_ack", (gjid, messageId))
    # do something with the message....

def onGroup_addParticipantsSuccess(self, gjid, jid):
    log ("Participant added success g=%s j=%s " % (gjid, jid))

def onGroup_removeParticipantsSuccess(self, gjid, jid):
    log ("Participant removed success g=%s j=%s " % (gjid, jid))
```